# How does printf() really perform?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

[This documentation](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) gives an example of how to write a varargs function, `printf()` .

As the documentation, `printf()` will find the first `%` in the string and use `va_arg(argp, int)` to get the first argument pointer; find the second `%` in the string and use `va_arg(argp, int)` again to get the second argument pointer......

So, I wrote a code snippet:

```
int Var = 0;

int Func (int X)
{
    Var = Var + X;
    return Var;
}

int main (void)
{
    printf ("%d\n%d", Func (3), Func (5));
}
```

It will print:

```
8    <-- 5+3
5    <-- 5
```

I know calling multiple functions in `printf()` **is undefined behavior**, but why not print:

```
3    <-- 3
8    <-- 3+5
```

**just as the sample code** in that [documentation](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html)?

ps: If my question is not clear, please help me edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order that function parameters are evaluated in C is *platform dependent* (not undefined, just unspecified).

See this blog that talks about it: [Funny thing about C parameter evaluation order…](http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/funny-thing-about-c-parameter-evaluation-order/)

If you want to force the order, you would call `Func()` before the `printf()`:

```
int a = Func(3);
int b = Func(5);
printf("%d\n%d", a, b);
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's true that parameter evaluation order isn't defined, parameter placement is. The so called **C calling convention** states that parameters are pushed to the stack from right to left. This order is needed precisely to support variable parameter functions. Normally, as each parameter is evaluated, it is inmediately pushed into the stack (although some obscure optimizations in order to optimize memory writes might alter this), so we could expect that parameter evaluarion works by evaluating them from right to left.

That would mean that `Func(5)` is first evaluated, pushes `5` into the stack, then `Func(3)` is evaluated, pushing `8` to the stack. Parameter order, as it will be printed by `printf` are `8` and `5`.